# Create a system user without password and home directory on Centos machine

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, password, useradd

I want to create system user without password and home directory. I found some similar solution but not properly get my answer. I am using a centos machine.

in ubuntu: `adduser mprobe --disabled-password --system --no-create-home --group`

its working but in centos it says disable-password not found.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK `adduser` isn't a coreutils command, [it's just a convenience script](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/useradd-vs-adduser), so it may vary drastically from distro to distro.
A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=centos%20create%20user%20without%20password) [yields](https://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-create-a-user-without-password-in-linux/), that password could be disabled for an existing user with `passwd -d <username>`. So my recommendation would be to:

```
sudo -s # Enter a root shell
```

then:

```
adduser mprobe --system --no-create-home --group # Create the user in question
passwd -d mprobe # Delete its password
exit # Drop root privileges
```